# Decode mailitems with different codepages to the same codepage / encoding

Tags: c#, outlook, codepages, msg

currently i'm working with the c# outlook interop classes to process .msg files (saved from exchange server).

The mails are saved with different mail.InternetCodepage because i need the content of the mail (= mail.Body) i have to decode the mail.body based on the codepage of the mail to utf8.

it would be possible to code a "IF codepage = 1234 .. " for every possible codepage, but i think there is a better way...

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, if you generate Unicode MSG files, the code page (PR_INTERNET_CPID) won't matter.

Secondly, Outlook Object Model (since it is IDispatch'able COM based) only deals with UTF-16 strings, so Outlook Object Model performs all the conversions for you.